# MongoDB: Optimization of Performance: Aggregation Pipeline (one collection) VS Aggregation plus Additional Query on Seperate Collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, nosql

I would like to know what is faster in terms of querying for mongodb.
Lets say I would like to search for income information based on areas
And a person can have many residencies in different states. And each polygon area would have an associated income for that individual.

I have outlined two options for querying this information, I would like to know which would be faster to search.

1) To have a single collection which has two types of documents.
Document1: has a geospatial index on it with polygons, and will have 
2dsphere index on it. It will be searched with aggregation to return ids that will link to document 2. Essentially taking the place of a relation in mysql.

Document2: has other information (lets say income amount) and different indexes, but has an id
which the first document also has to reference it.
And also has an index on income amount.

The two documents are searched with an aggregation pipeline.
Stage 1 of pipeline:  searching document1 geospatially for items and getting the id value .
Stage 2 of pipeline: using id found in document1 to search second document. As well searched by income type.

2) Seperating out the documents where each has its own collection and avoiding aggregation.
querying collection1 for geospatial and using the person id's found to query collection2 for income info.

3) A third option involving polyglot database, a combination of mongodb and postigs: Query postgis for the id and then use that to search mongodb collecton. I am including this option since I believe postgis to be faster for querying geospatially than mogo but I am curious if the speed of postgis will not matter due to latency of now querying two databases.

The end goal is to pull back data based on a geospatial radius. One geospatial polygon representing area where the person lives and does business for that income.
maps to 1 relational id and each relational id maps to many sets of data. Essentially I have a many to 1 to many relationship. 
Many geospatials map to 1 person which maps to many data sets.

Comment: In all honesty you will not get accurate advice without showing proposed samples of what you want to do. I can quote various scenarios where even seemingly simple aggregation statements are beaten by running queries in parallel, and then again I've seen the reverse. It's all about data and usage. So the key thing here it to **test**. But more importantly, maybe you should be describing "What you want to achieve" rather than describing "How you think you will do it". The former will get you more insight than the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally keep collections limited to a single type of document.

Solution 1 will not work. You cannot use the aggregation pipeline the way you are describing (if I'm understanding you correctly). Also, it sounds as though you are thinking in a relational way about a solution using a non-relational database.

Solution 2 will work but it will not have optimum performance. This solution sounds even more like a relational database solution where the collections are being treated like tables.

Solution 3 will probably work but as you said it will now require two databases.

All three of these solutions are progressively pulling these two types of documents further and further away from one another. I believe the best solution for a document database like MongoDB is to embed this data. It's impossible without a real example of your documents and without a clear understanding of your application to suggest an exact solution. But in general embedding data is preferred over creating relationships between documents in MongoDB. As long as no document will ever get to be over 16MB it's worth looking into whether embedding is the right solution.